# mongodb count num of distinct values per field/key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a query for calculating how many distinct values a field contains in DB.

f.e I have a field for country and there are 8 types of country values (spain, england, france, etc...)

If someone adds more documents with a new country I would like the query to return 9.

Is there easier way then group and count?

Comment: Have you looked at the [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) framework?

Comment: Or [map-reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB select count(distinct x) on an indexed column - count unique results for large data sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782566/mongodb-select-countdistinct-x-on-an-indexed-column-count-unique-results-for). I posted my answer there.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

MongoDB has a [`distinct` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) which returns an array of distinct values for a field; you can check the length of the array for a count.

There is a shell [`db.collection.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) helper as well:

```
> db.countries.distinct('country');
[ "Spain", "England", "France", "Australia" ]

> db.countries.distinct('country').length
4
```

As noted in the MongoDB documentation:

> Results must not be larger than the maximum BSON size (16MB). If your results exceed the maximum BSON size, use the aggregation pipeline to retrieve distinct values using the `$group` operator, as described in [Retrieve Distinct Values with the Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#std-label-aggregation-group-distinct-values).

Comment: this doesn't really work if your number of distinct values is too high... if you were looking at distinct names of people in the world or something. do you have an answer that scales?

Comment: 1+ for length. i was struggling to find something like that. Thanks.

Comment: I don´t know why they don´t use count() there as well

Comment: @MarianKlühspies - because it's just a javascript array, which uses the length property to count the number of elements.

Comment: Just what I was looking for... TY

Comment: @UpTheCreek. so what if javascript..as end user i am least bothered if underlying is python or javascript etc.. what's the problem to keep it as count.just a syntactic sugar right?   Anyways , the developer, manager or company of the product decides what to name :)

Comment: This doesn't work when you have millions or billions of records.....

Comment: @rohitcoder If you have millions or billions of documents to iterate for distinct values, I suggest posting a new question with details of your environment and use case. I expect you will be using a more modern version of MongoDB than this discussion from Feb 2013, when MongoDB 2.2 was the latest server release and the Aggregation Framework had just been introduced :). I edited my answer to include a note from the `distinct` documentation which recommends the Aggregation Framework for larger result sets, but there are other approaches and operators available in modern versions of MongoDB.

Answer (score 166):

Here is example of using aggregation API. To complicate the case we're grouping by case-insensitive words from array property of the document.

```
db.articles.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            keywords: { $not: {$size: 0} }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$keywords" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {$toLower: '$keywords'},
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: { $gte: 2 }
        }
    },
    { $sort : { count : -1} },
    { $limit : 100 }
]);
```

that give result such as

```
{ "_id" : "inflammation", "count" : 765 }
{ "_id" : "obesity", "count" : 641 }
{ "_id" : "epidemiology", "count" : 617 }
{ "_id" : "cancer", "count" : 604 }
{ "_id" : "breast cancer", "count" : 596 }
{ "_id" : "apoptosis", "count" : 570 }
{ "_id" : "children", "count" : 487 }
{ "_id" : "depression", "count" : 474 }
{ "_id" : "hiv", "count" : 468 }
{ "_id" : "prognosis", "count" : 428 }
```

Comment: Logged in just to + this answer. Thanks! btw if you are doing it on a unique field, just remove the unwind line.

Comment: @RichieRich, `unwind` is necessary because the code is grouping individual values of an array field which matches how `distinct` works.

Comment: @Paul what Richie said is that if the grouping is done just "regular" field (string, int etc.) then you don't need the unwind step. Isn't it correct?

Comment: @guyarad `unwind` is necessary when working with arrays.

Comment: +1 for the answer, exactly the thing I was working on, however distinct has its own charms but this is just gold :) -- anyhow I have to read more about aggregates to achieve desired set of results to filter data

Answer (score 33):

With MongoDb 3.4.4 and newer, you can leverage the use of **[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)** operator and a **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** pipeline to get the counts.

For example, suppose you have a collection of users with different roles and you would like to calculate the distinct counts of the roles. You would need to run the following aggregate pipeline:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "$toLower": "$role" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "counts": {
            "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" }
        }
    } },
    { "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" }
    } }    
])
```

**Example Output**

```
{
    "user" : 67,
    "superuser" : 5,
    "admin" : 4,
    "moderator" : 12
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but it is helpful nonetheless. I wonder how this performs compared to `.distinct()`.

Comment: Thanks! worked exactly the way I need.

Answer (score 21):

I wanted a more concise answer and I came up with the following using the documentation at [aggregates and group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#retrieve-distinct-values)

```js
db.countries.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": "$country", "count":{"$sum": 1}}}])
```

Comment: @Kr1 how to add the value of each country to get the total?

Comment: thank you vert much exactly what I need and clean to read.

Answer (score 10):

You can leverage on [Mongo Shell Extensions](https://github.com/gabrielelana/mongodb-shell-extensions#Collection-distinctAndCount). It's a single .js import that you can append to your `$HOME/.mongorc.js`, or programmatically, if you're coding in Node.js/io.js too.

**Sample**

For each distinct value of field counts the occurrences in documents optionally filtered by query

> > `db.users.distinctAndCount('name', {name: /^a/i})`

```
{
  "Abagail": 1,
  "Abbey": 3,
  "Abbie": 1,
  ...
}
```

The field parameter could be an array of fields

> > `db.users.distinctAndCount(['name','job'], {name: /^a/i})`

```
{
  "Austin,Educator" : 1,
  "Aurelia,Educator" : 1,
  "Augustine,Carpenter" : 1,
  ...
}
```

Comment: how would i import this in node?

Comment: `require("./script.js")`, i suppose

Comment: right, but I wasn't able to get the functions inside. How do I use them. They are defined as db.protoptype.distinctAndCount

Comment: There's a how-to section in the repo's readme (RTFM!1!!1!) basically, put the `.mongorc.js`file into your home dir. Done.

Answer (score 10):

I use this query:

```
var collection = "countries"; var field = "country"; 
db[collection].distinct(field).forEach(function(value){print(field + ", " + value + ": " + db[collection].count({[field]: value}))})
```

Output:

```
countries, England: 3536
countries, France: 238
countries, Australia: 1044
countries, Spain: 16
```

This query first distinct all the values, and then count for each one of them the number of occurrences.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write this same query in php laravel?

Comment: what is host here in this query ?

Comment: @HeenaPatil Good catch!
I had two bugs in the query, I fixed it now. The `hosts` was the name of my collection in my db... sorry for that.
The other issue that I also fixed tried to call `db.collection` which I fixed to `db[collection]`.
Thanks!

Comment: that is what I am looking for, but I was hoping there is  a one line query to handle it, Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

To find distinct in `field_1` in collection but we want some `WHERE` condition too than we can do like following :

`db.your_collection_name.distinct('field_1', {WHERE condition here and it should return a document})`

So, find number distinct `names` from a collection where age > 25 will be like :

`db.your_collection_name.distinct('names', {'age': {"$gt": 25}})`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

If you're on MongoDB 3.4+, you can use `$count` in an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: '$country' } },
  { $count: 'countOfUniqueCountries' }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1**
If you are using find() then the solution for that is:

```
const getDistinctCountryCount = async (req, res) => {
  const countryCount = await(await db.model.distinct('country')).length;
  console.log("countryCount: ", countryCount);
}
```

You have to first await the query result, then await to get the length of it.

**Case 2**
If you are using Aggregate then the solution for that is:

```
db.model.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: '$country' } },
  { $count: 'countOfDistinchCountries' }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest query I've found to get a sorted count of all distincts:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
    "$group": {"_id": "$myField", "count":{"$sum": 1}}
  },
  { "$sort": {"count": -1}}
])
```