# faster way to count distinct value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying to count a distinct value with pymongo, my code looks like :

```
account_log = mongo["account_log"].find({"uuid": guid}).distinct("logged_number")
total["account"] = len(mongo["group_member"].find({ "group_id": {"$in": groups}}).distinct("phone"))
```

the distinct inside len() was very very slow, is there another way to count the distinct result, thank you

Comment: Please check the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924495/mongodb-count-num-of-distinct-values-per-field-key

Comment: @krishnaPrasad i already check that answer, and i ask "faster way", not just counting a distinct value

Comment: If given [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695921/3710490) doesn't feet your expectation, there is no any "faster way" to count distinct values.