# Count the number of item without duplicate in mongodb by node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my json

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    name:'rakib'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name:'sakib'
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name:'sakib'
  },
  {
    id:4,
    name:'akib'
  }
]
```

In this, I want to count the number of names but not duplicate by node js in MongoDB
My count will be: 3 ('rakib', 'sakib', 'akib')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb count num of distinct values per field/key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924495/mongodb-count-num-of-distinct-values-per-field-key)

Answer (score 0):

1. `$group` - Group by `null` and with `$addToSet` to add `name` to `names` array without duplicates.
2. `$project` - Decorate the output documents. With `$size` to count the size of the `names` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      names: {
        $addToSet: "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: {
        $size: "$names"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pyFjI2QcQR-)