# select count of unique elements in pymongo

Tags: python, database, pymongo

How do I get the number of all unique `name` fields in `table` collections? In SQL the code would look something like this:

```
select count(*) from (
    select name from table
    group by name
)
```

My first guess was this

```
aggregated_sums = table.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": "$name", "count":{"$sum": 1}}}])
print(len(list(aggregated_sums)))
```

But I'm afraid that in my scenario aggregated_sums might contain tens of millions of records.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a correct approach as per [MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#retrieve-distinct-values). `Distinct` has limitations, and might not be applicable in your case - see e.g. discussion under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14928718).

The trick here is to use `count` on a separate step from `group`:

```
table.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name"
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "unique_keys"
  }
])
```

I have tested it on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/), `count` clause on the group stage is not mandatory. Of course, the result returned is an aggregated count already, no need to call `len` afterwards.

Comment: wouldn't len(list(aggregated_sums)) take a long time to execute in case aggregated_sums has millions of items?

Comment: @diplodocus Actually, I probably misread, apologies. I will edit the answer shortly.