# Distinct values of a key in a sub-document MongoDB (100 million records)

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, bigdata

I have 100 million records in my "sample" collection. I want to have another collection with all of the distinct user names "user.screen_name"

I have the following structure in my mongodb database "sample" collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("515af34297c2f607b822a54b"),
"text" : "random text goes here",
"user" :
  {
    "id" : 972863366,
    "screen_name" : "xname",
    "verified" : false,
    "time_zone" : "Amsterdam",
   }
}
```

When I try things like "distinct('user.id).length" I get the following error:

```
    "errmsg" : "exception: distinct too big, 16mb cap",
```

I need an **efficient** way to have another collection with only {"user_name": "name"} of distinct users in my "sample" collection. so then I can query the size of this new database and get the number of distinct users. (and for further analysis in the future)

Comment: You tagged this with mapreduce, did you try to use MongoDB's mapreduce?

Comment: Not really, I know that the answer might be using mapreduce, however, I am not really familiar with  with the syntax and concept.

Comment: Start with the documentation. It's a good place to start. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782566/mongodb-select-countdistinct-x-on-an-indexed-column-count-unique-results-for) and it worked fine :) .. I'll keep the thread and add my code in case someone needs it.

```
var SOURCE = db.sample;
var DEST = db.distinct;
DEST.drop();
map = function() {
  emit( this.user.screen_name , {count: 1});
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
  var count = 0;

  values.forEach(function(v) {
    count += v['count'];   
  });

  return {count: count};
};

res = SOURCE.mapReduce( map, reduce, 
    { out: 'distinct', 
     verbose: true
    }
    );

print( "distinct count= " + res.counts.output );
print( "distinct count=", DEST.count() );
```

Regards