# Is the aggregation output order stable for the purposes of pagination?

Tags: mongodb

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640492/problems-with-queries-in-mongodb) suggested doing the following

```
db.user_tracking.aggregate( {$limit: X}, {$skip: Y}, {$group: {_id: "$q"} )
```

Is the output ordering guaranteed to be stable and consistent? If I page through results can I guarantee that I will recieve every value exactly once?

Assuming the collection doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is stable as long as the collection doesn't change. Changes include *updates* to documents as well however. But if you can do a sort (as first operand), that would probably a good addition too. Please make sure you have an index on that though.

Comment: Index to help the operation of the grouping or to ensure stability?

Comment: The index would help the $sort, just to make sure it doesn't need to read all documents to do the $sort. A $sort makes the order stable and also defined. Without the sort you get "natural order", which isn't really specified.